# how to understand few symbols and syntaxs in Julia?

Tags: syntax, julia

I am very new to Julia language, so I started to read the documentation and all built-in functions. Now, I am learning one github project for my work. Since I am more comfortable with Python, I tried to translate Julia's code to python by my understanding, but I got a few weird syntaxes that I didn't understand and I got stuck with them. Can anyone point me out the meaning of those syntaxes? Thanks in advance!

**syntax that I don't understand**

those julia code line that I didn't understand because I didn't find them either in documentations.

`var1 = Tuple{Integer, Vector}[]`

here we declare object var 1, what's a real example for that? what's the python version?

also if `X::Matrix, n::Int`, then what's the meaning of `?` in the below? How should I code this in python?

`K = [( i >= j ? dot(view(X,:,i), view(X,:,j)) : 0.0 )::Float64 for i=1:n, j=1:n]`

how should we code up this in python?

Also, I am not sure about meaning of `->` in below:

```
for i=1:n 
      id_i = find(x -> x[1] == i, var1)
      xi_i_list =  map(x -> x[2], var1[id_i])

how should we translate this into python?
```

lastly, I just don't understand the meaning of `.>` in below:

```
act= zeros(100)
alpha = zeros(10)

  for i=1:100
    idx = find(x::Tuple{Integer, Vector} -> x[1] == i, var1)
    act[i] = sum(alpha[idx] .> 1e-3)
```

As a newbie, I am trying to understand the role of `find()`, `map()`. To the best, I wish I could write the above Julia code with Python. But I have a hard time understanding the code. Can anyone give possible interpretations and corresponding python codes for learning purposes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: x-ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/understanding-few-syntax-of-julia-code/53514/10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the Julia documentation offers a list of [Noteworthy differences from Python](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-Python). Now to each question:

> ```
> var1 = Tuple{Integer, Vector}[]
> ```
>
> here we declare object var 1, what's a real example for that? what's the python version?

`Vector`, which is sugar for `Array{T,1} where T`, means a 1D array with elements of any type.
`Tuple{Integer, Vector}` is thus a tuple with an `Integer` and a `Vector`, like, `(1, [1, 2])` for example.
`var1` is just an empty vector of such tuples.
You can `push!` elements like the latter into `var1` to create a "real" example:

```
julia> var1 = Tuple{Integer, Vector}[]
Tuple{Integer,Array{T,1} where T}[]

julia> push!(var1, (1, [1, 2]))
1-element Array{Tuple{Integer,Array{T,1} where T},1}:
 (1, [1, 2])

julia> push!(var1, (2, [3.0, "foo", 4]))
2-element Array{Tuple{Integer,Array{T,1} where T},1}:
 (1, [1, 2])
 (2, Any[3.0, "foo", 4])
```

---

> what's the meaning of `?`

You can type `?` to access the "help" mode in julia, and then ask it what `?` is. From its documentation:

> ```
> a ? b : c
> ```
>
> Short form for conditionals; read "if a, evaluate b otherwise evaluate c". Also known as the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).
>
> This syntax is equivalent to `if a; b else c end`, but is often used to emphasize the value `b`-or-`c` which is being used as part of a larger expression, rather than the side effects that evaluating `b` or `c` may have.
>
> See the manual section on control flow for more details.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> julia> x = 1; y = 2;
>
> julia> println(x > y ? "x is larger" : "y is larger")
> y is larger
> ```

---

> not sure about meaning of `->`

This is just to create an [anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions).

---

> I just don't understand the meaning of `.>`

This is just the element-by-element "greater than" operator `>`. See the documentation on [dotted operators](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. How should we simplify this: `K = [( i >= j ? dot(view(X,:,i), view(X,:,j)) : 0.0 )::Float64 for i=1:n, j=1:n]`? how can we write this line in python? if `idi=collect(1:10)`, then what's the meaning of this: `map(10 -> idi(1, 10), collect(1:12))`? Could you show me use case of `find()` and `map()` in python version? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well I would have written it as `K = LowerTriangular(x⋅y for x in eachcol(X), y in eachcol(X))`. Not sure about python.

Comment: Not sure what your `map(10 -> idi(1, 10)` means, since the `10` on the left is not a variable.

Comment: And not sure about python, no, sorry.